# Microphone noise reduction

Tags: audio, microphone

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 with dualboot. But i have problem with microphone noise. I can not find any noise reduction in Ubuntu.

Sound quality is for me quite important, because i am talking with friends on TeamSpeak, recording videos on youtube and doing livestreams.

I have microphone in headset, and i never had any problem with it in Windows.

I tried alsamixer, but it does not help, because it only lowered my volume, but noise is still here.

Please do not post here applications like audacity, because i need realtime reduction, because livestreams and talking on teamspeak.

PC: Desktop

Sound card: Realtek® ALC892